# Does an stereographical projection of a physical plane have any physical meaning?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, phase-space, complex-systems, bloch-sphere

Mathematically, an arbitrary 2D plane can be mapped onto a sphere by stereographical projection. Each line on the plane is equivalent to each line on the sphere. If the sphere rotates under the $SO(3)$ group, the plane is transformed under the Möbius group.

[image]

If the plane has some physical meanings (coordinate plane, phase plane), then does its stereographical projection have some physical meanings too? What happens if the plane is multi-dimensional, and the group is different than $SO(n)$? Would it be just math, not physics anymore? How about the group $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ in particle physics?

Since it is the Riemann sphere in complex analysis, [complex dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_dynamics) might have an answer this, but on the first skim it seems to be more about fractals, not stereographical projection.

<sub>Some of my related questions:

• [Is there a relation between phase plane and complex plane?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359010/41634)

• [Roadmap to understand the link between harmonic analysis and Riemann sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2446482/157643)</sub>

Comment: This post (v3) seems to be a list question. Riemann surfaces are e.g. used in string theory; the Bloch sphere is a Riemann sphere; etc.

Comment: Is list question accepted?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#Applications)  on the Riemann sphere lists some applications in physics.